# How to open an another file by path in *.log in Vim

Tags: vim

I use Vim to read a *.log file. 
I want to open these referred source file quickly.

Below is the a section of my log file.

```
------------------------------
// ...
   at clquo.infrastructure.serviceagents.httpclientwrapper.sendasync(httprequestmessage httprequest, cancellationtoken token) in w:\q\main\httpclientwrapper.cs:line 61
   at clquo.infrastructure.serviceagents.webapiclient.executerequest[tresult](uri route, httprequestmessage httprequest) in w:\q\main\webapiclient.cs:line 92
// ...
------------------------------
```

Now I want to open file '**w:\q\main\httpclientwrapper.cs**' quickly in a vertical split.

Instead of type "**:split w:\q\main\httpclientwrapper.cs**" command, is there some quick method to open the file in vim directly?
I am lazy. I do not want to type the full path.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You move the cursor onto the file name and then hit `gf`.

From Vims help:

> Edit the file whose name is under or after the cursor. Mnemonic: "goto file".

See `:help gf`.

You could also visually select the filename and then hit `gf`. See `:help v_gf` for that.

To open the file in a new window (aka split), use `<C-w><C-f>`.
 is 'Ctrl+w'
 is 'Ctrl+f'

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am afraid that you answer did not resolve my problem.

If I try you command, I got below error. I guess it is due to the filename match pattern did not work well with my *.log file :(.

E447: Can't find file "w:\q\main\projects\infrastructure.serviceagents\crm\accountserviceagent.cs:line" in path

Comment: I can substitute ':line' with ' :line' to help Vim to match the pattern correctly. 
But, is there some method to open the file in a split window instead of replace current one.

Comment: @JosephCen See update for "split". Because of the `:line` I mentioned visual. Go to begin of filename, hit `v` and move to end of filename. Then hit `gf` or `<C-w><C-f>`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error is the trailing `:line` attached to the filespec, you're faced with a problem that is specific to Windows-style filenames:

- You could remove the `:` character from the [`'isfname'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27isfname%27) option (`:set isfname-=:`), but then the *drive letter* part would also be excluded, so you effectively could only open files from within the same drive.
- You could use the *visual mode* variant of `gf` (as suggested by @Ralf's answer), but that requires manual selection.
- Vim falls back to [`'includeexpr'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27includeexpr%27) if the parsed filespec does not exist. With that, you can automatically remove the trailing `:line`:

```
:set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,':line$','','')
```